# How to calculate the current week in the month in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My goal is to find the date of a particular day in a given week of that month. Say for example, I want to know the date on May 2nd week's Friday.
I can get the following via Time and Date classes.

Week number of current year (considering Sunday as first)

```
    Time.strftime(%U)
```

Day of the week (0..7)

```
    Time.strftime(%w)
```

But how I get the what week (1st,2nd,3rd,4th or 5th) of the month it is in?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you define your first week? Or when starts the 2nd week? Example: The [Iso week date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#First_week) defines week 01 in a year as the week with the year's first Thursday in it.

Comment: Yes. according to ISO standards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to handle the requirements you listed, I would suggest writing a helper function to get the number of the week in a month.

```
def get_month_week(date_or_time, start_day = :sunday)

  date = date_or_time.to_date
  week_start_format = start_day == :sunday ? '%U' : '%W'

  month_week_start = Date.new(date.year, date.month, 1)
  month_week_start_num = month_week_start.strftime(week_start_format).to_i
  month_week_start_num += 1 if month_week_start.wday > 4 # Skip first week if doesn't contain a Thursday

  month_week_index = date.strftime(week_start_format).to_i - month_week_start_num
  month_week_index + 1 # Add 1 so that first week is 1 and not 0

end
```

This can then just be called like so:

```
get_month_week(Date.today)
```

If you really feel like monkey-patching is something you want, you can add to the Date class:

```
class Date

  def month_week(start_day = :sunday)

    week_start_format = start_day == :sunday ? '%U' : '%W'

    month_week_start = Date.new(self.year, self.month, 1)
    month_week_start_num = month_week_start.strftime(week_start_format).to_i
    month_week_start_num += 1 if month_week_start.wday > 4 # Skip first week if doesn't contain a Thursday

    month_week_index = self.strftime(week_start_format).to_i - month_week_start_num
    month_week_index + 1 # Add 1 so that first week is 1 and not 0

  end

end
```

And this can be called on a date or time like so:

```
Date.today.month_week
```

or

```
Time.current.to_date.month_week
```

I would advise against this since it may collide with other libraries or violate least-surprise for other developers working on the project.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
current_time = Time.zone.now
beginning_of_the_month = current_time.beginning_of_month
puts current_time.strftime('%U').to_i - beginning_of_the_month.strftime('%U').to_i + 1
```

Or

```
Time.parse('2015-01-08').strftime('%U').to_i - Time.parse('2015-01-01').strftime('%U').to_i + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The [week-of-month](https://github.com/sachin87/week-of-month) gem will do this. First add the gem to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'week_of_month'
```

Then use it like:

```
Time.now.week_of_month
```

If you need the week to start on Monday instead of Sunday.  Stick this in an initializer:

```
WeekOfMonth.configuration.monday_active = true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def number_of_weeks_month(start_of_month, count, end_of_month)
    if start_date > end_of_month
        return count
    else
        number_of_weeks_month(start_date.end_of_week + 1, count + 1, end_of_month)
    end
end
```

`number_of_weeks_month(Date.parse("2017-11-01"),0,Date.parse("2017-11-30"))`
for the month on November it gives 4

Answer (score 0):

There is a cool way to calc it in Rails:

```
dt.cweek - dt.beginning_of_month.cweek + 1
```